# Right-Rotate of AVL is giving problems?

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, avl-tree

I am writing right-rotate for AVL tree.But it is giving Runtime error.Currently I am ignoring height part of AVL tree.I will take care of that later.But just applying right rotate at 5 is giving problems.Please help. 
AVL tree I have used is :

```
                                  9(Root)

                5(Left Child)                          13(Right Child)

            3                 7                  11                       17
      2
1
```

C Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>


struct AVLTree
{
  int data;
  struct AVLTree *left;
  struct AVLTree *right;
};



struct AVLTree *RightRotate(struct AVLTree *rootop)
{
    struct AVLTree *A = rootop->left;
    rootop->left = A->right;
    A->right = rootop;

    return A;
}

int main()
{
    struct AVLTree * root = (struct AVLTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct AVLTree));
    root-> data = 9;
    struct AVLTree * l = (struct AVLTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct AVLTree));
    l -> data = 5;
    struct AVLTree * ll = (struct AVLTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct AVLTree));
    ll -> data = 3;
    ll -> left = ll -> right = NULL;
    struct AVLTree * lll = (struct AVLTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct AVLTree));
    lll -> data = 2;
    lll -> left = lll -> right = NULL;
    ll->left = lll;
    struct AVLTree * llll = (struct AVLTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct AVLTree));
    llll -> data = 1;
    llll -> left = llll -> right = NULL;
    lll->left = llll;
    struct AVLTree * lr = (struct AVLTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct AVLTree));
    lr -> data = 7;
    lr -> left = lr -> right = NULL;
    l -> left = ll;
    l -> right = lr;
    struct AVLTree * r = (struct AVLTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct AVLTree));
    r -> data = 13;
    struct AVLTree * rl = (struct AVLTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct AVLTree));
    rl -> data = 11;
    rl -> left = rl -> right = NULL;
    struct AVLTree * rr = (struct AVLTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct AVLTree));
    rr -> data = 17;
    rr -> left = rr -> right = NULL;
    r -> left = rl;
    r -> right = rr;
    root -> left = l;
    root -> right = r;




    RightRotate(l);
    printf("Root is %d\n",root->data);

    printf("Left is %d\n",l->data);
    printf("Left left is %d\n",l->left->data);
    printf("Left right is %d\n",l->right->data);

    printf("Left Ka Left is %d\n",ll->data);
    printf("LL left is %d\n",ll->left->data);

    printf("Left Ka Left Ka Left is %d\n",lll->data);
    printf("LLL left is %d\n",lll->left->data);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What problems? Can you be more specific? Does it segfault? Have you tried debugged?

Comment: Just Runtime error.Do you think calling function is wrong?If I put                l = RightRotate(l);                                                                                          it works but gives wrong values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write something like `l = RightRotate(l)`, because your `RightRotate` function returns `struct AVLTree *`.

Comment: If I Put `l = RightRotate(l)` then it gives wrong values for ll i.e `l->left->data = 2` and `ll->data = 3` (where l->left = ll) gives different values.

Comment: First, it's normal if you get Runtime error in this situation, because after `RightRotate(l)`, you set `l->left=NULL`, so `l->left->data` get error, in fact, this is a `segmentation fault` because you wanna get data from a null pointer. Second, you may try `ll=RightRotate(ll)`, that's meaningful with AVL tree. And last, are you sure that include `malloc.h` instead of `stdlib.h`?

Comment: Yeah it should be `stdlib.h`not malloc.h .But how is `l->left = NULL` after `l = RightRotate(l)`?New `l = 3` and 'l->left = 2'.And yeah `ll=RightRotate(ll)` can also be done.But that also is giving wrong values?

Comment: They're not wrong values, they have reasons. Because you set `l->left= an address(e.g.23ef, it's ll's address)` first, and then we reset `ll`'s address to `lll`'s address, but `l->left` remains `23ef`. So if you wish `left left is 2` just reset `l->left=ll`

Comment: I am setting `l->left = NULL` but `l` itself is changing from 5 to 3.So `l->left` is not Null anymore.But still `ll` is coming as 3 whereas it should be 2?

Comment: And `lll->data` is still coming as 2 instead of 1?

Comment: And `llll->data` is still coming as 1 where it should be null?

Comment: In your code above, change `RightRotate(l);` to `ll = RightRotate(ll);` and add `l->left = ll` under it. (Not `l->left = NULL`). In this case `ll->data=lll->data=l->left->data=2`.